# PayUbiz success url not called if using 3rd party apps

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, payment-gateway, payumoney, payu

I have integrated PayUbiz payment gateway in one of my clients website. It works fine if customer pays using Cards or Net Banking, but when any customer tries to pay the amount using 3rd party apps eg: Google Pay, I am unable to capture the payment success callback from PayU (The payment is made successfully and also gets updated on PayUbiz Admin Dashboard, but not in our system). I thing customers are not going back to the website page and hence PayUbiz fails to call/redirect to success URL of our website.

How can I handle such situation?

Website is implemented using Codeigniter PHP framework and MySQL as Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User will not necessarily come to the browser after UPI payment mode. In that case you should make a cron on server and on that cron you will have to call payubiz Rest API: https://api.payu.in/payments

This api will give you all payment Id and will redirect url. You have to trigger that redirect url manually using curl.

Here is the Rest API link: [https://developer.payubiz.in/v2/documentation/index.html#tag/PaymentService%2Fpaths%2F~1payments%2Fpost](https://developer.payubiz.in/v2/documentation/index.html#tag/PaymentService%2Fpaths%2F%7E1payments%2Fpost)

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful. This idea already came to my mind. But we need customers to fill one mandatory form after successful payment which gets open after success URL hits. Also after that we are creating a receipt which they need to print.

Comment: At last I had to solve it using cron job only. Thanks for the answer though!